# Opencv:: Multi-template matching with one template in real time application

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to use one template to do multiple template on video streaming, is it possible? 
I have tried using for loop to make the code runs more than 1 time, however, the first rectangle disappear when the second ones come out.
Following is my code, I am using ROS.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include "std_msgs/Int8.h"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global Variables
Mat img; Mat templ; Mat result;
char const* image_window = "Source Image";
char const* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;


// This is the position of line in the image
int line_position = 0;

void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
    /// Source image to display
    Mat img_display;
    img.copyTo( img_display );
    int image_width = img.cols;

    /// Create the result matrix
    int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

    result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );



        /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
        Point matchLoc;

        minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

        /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
        if ( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
        { matchLoc = minLoc; }
        else
        { matchLoc = maxLoc; }

        /// Show me what you got
        rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );
        rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );

    imshow( image_window, img_display );
    imshow( result_window, result );

    return;
}

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    templ = imread("/home/davon/catkin_ws/src/test/src/temp1.png");
    /// Create windows
    namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( result_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Create Trackbar
    char const* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
    createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

    try {

        img = cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image;
        MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );
        waitKey(30);
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.", msg->encoding.c_str());
    }


}//end of ImageCallback


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    cv::startWindowThread();
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("ardrone/front/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);


    ros::init(argc, argv, "line_position");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Int8>("line_position", 30);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(30);
    while (ros::ok())
    {
        std_msgs::Int8 position;
        position.data = line_position;
        ROS_INFO("%d", position.data);
        chatter_pub.publish(position);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }


    ros::spin();
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32095085/5008845) can probably help

Answer (score 0):

Use a threshold value and a while loop to check for multiple templates in the image

```
while(true)
{
    int threshold = 0.9;
    double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
    Point matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

    /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
    if ( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
    else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }

    /// Show me what you got
    if(maxval >threshold && 0!=matchLoc .x && 0!=matchLoc .y )
{
    rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );
    rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );
}
 else
{
break;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it will still show 1 rectangle only.

Comment: did you tried debugging it, does it enters the else after first match?